# Using a field to define label font size in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, labeling, os-mastermap

I have a tab file of ordnance survey MasterMap data, this was obtained from a client so I have no way of re-downloading it.

Usually when I have these files the text is automatically displayed according to a number of fields (e.g size, angle etc.). However this file I have everything is displayed as lines.

I have used style override to remove the lines and have turned labelling on.

However each label has the same text size and makes the map quite unreadable when zoomed out to the level I require.

Is there any way in MapInfo to set the font size/height to that defined in a field in the table for the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the labels and override the settings based on zoom location (scale dependent)

Use the Label Override Rules to control the Zoom Range and the Text Placement options.

This simply a right click on the layer properties in the table of contents (with layer control visible)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, currently MapInfo Pro doesn't allow you to label the objects individually within the same layer.

The only option I can think of, is to create a number of queries, add these to the map and set specific label settings for each of the queries.

In that way the labels can depend on the query.